# List<T> to database and back again

Tags: c#, database, list, ado.net, bulkinsert

So im trying to write my list to a database and ive got some questions. First of all nothing seems to get saved into the database but theres no errors that would cause a crash sofar and I know for a fact that this piece of code has worked in the past for me:

```
    public void saveToDb(int var1, string var2)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into [table] (col1, col2) VALUES (@param1, @param2)", conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", var1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", var2);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
```

I have a three piece layer going on, ui, logic and DAL. First of all it didnt work with the database and the app.config files in the DAL class library so those were moved to the main class library and now its not whining about the database already existing and it finds my connection string.

To send the data into this method im doing it this way:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
        {
            da.saveToDb(myList.val1, myList.val2);
        }
```

Its not giving me an error in the code but nothing seems to be saved or is resetted when I stop the program but I dont know which but I can see the variable being passed correctly by printing them before doing the insert so im guessing the Db is resetted? Is it putting my db into the debug folder and flushing it everytime or what?

Another thing is last time I did this it was a form so there was always going to be just one insert at a time, right now my list of objects could contain anywhere from 1 to alot of objects and with this way I would be opening and closing the db connection once for each object in my list right? How do you do bulk inserts? Been reading about datasets but they all seem to be about reading from a database not writing so im not sure about that. I did read from a database in another project using Dataset and adapter so that shouldnt be a problem but how do I bulk send a list into a table? To make it abit more tricky I cant just convert the entire list because of 10 propertys 8 is going to go into one table and the remaining 2 is to go in a second table so I would need to loop them and add the respective property to the respective dataset (or what you use).

*edit*

Well ive now made some adjustments and im trying two methods and none of which work but neither gives an error either which is getting frustrating.

First method:

```
    public void saveToDb(int val1, string val2)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["[MyConnectionString]"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into [table] (val1, val2) VALUES (@param1, @param2)", conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", val1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", val2);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
```

And the second I try to sqlbulkcopy a table:

```
    public void SaveToDb()
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["[MyConnectionString]"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {
                bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("col1", "col1");
                bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("col2", "col1");
                bulk.DestinationTableName = "[table]";

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Open");
                bulk.WriteToServer(tab);
                foreach (DataRow row in tab.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(item.ToString());
                    }
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("sending");
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("closing");
        }
    }
```

I shouldnt have to map it since the table contains the exact same columns as the table with the same naming (upper/lower case) but it gets weird with the primary key which increments so I mapped it so it should add the increment automatically but nothing gets inserted, the print sure enough shows the values but if I comment out the mapping I get an error saying that null cant be assigned (which is true my table wont take nulls) but the value shouldnt be null since its there in the table?

Comment: I'm assuming that you have looked in the database to make sure these records aren't being inserted, right?

Comment: Don't use a global connection but use the `using-statement` instead for the `connection` and the `SqlCommand` which closes the connection implicitely. This works also in case of an exception. Your connection would stay open.

Comment: I did look at the db and thats some good advice there thanks Tim.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you forgot the index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
        da.saveToDb(myList[i].val1, myList[i].val2);
    }
```

Comment: Yea I noticed that but its there in the code just missed it when typing it here :p.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the connection object. 
var cn = new SqlConnection(). 
Then you call open on the connection object.

connection.command will give access to the command object.

Comment: The connection object is global but ill change that according to Tims comment and this one.